# I am trying to return a list of records in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, list, asp.net-core

I have a fixed list of

```
List<int> values = new List<int>() {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
```

I can give 2 input named `startValue` and `endValue` and it will return a `List<int>`.

**Examples:**

**#1**

```
startValue = 0
endValue = 4
returned List: {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}
```

**#2**

```
startValue = 1
endValue = 6
returned List: {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}
```

**#3**

```
startValue =  6
endValue = 4
returned List: {6, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4}
```

I have implemented in linq.

```
List<int> days = new List<int> { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
List<int> excpt = new List<int> { startDay, endDay };
List<int> fDays = new List<int>();

fDays = days.Except(excpt).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

My idea would be to use `LinkedList` collection like that:

```
List<int> days = new List<int> { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };

var startDay = 6;
var endDay = 4;

var linked = new LinkedList<int>(days);
var result = new List<int>();
var current = linked.Find(startDay);
result.Add(current.Value);

var finished = false;
while (!finished){
    current = current.Next ?? current.List.First;
    result.Add(current.Value);
    
    if (current.Value == endDay)
    {
        finished = true;
    }
}
```

Obviously you would have to implement all the protection against null values etc. But concept would work as you like

Comment: Side note: you can turn `while` into more compact `for`: `for (var finished = false; !finished; finished = current.Value == endDay) {...}`

Comment: I agree it would remove few lines of code. I tend to use basic structure and code patterns for making things easier to read. I understand your code but I have to admit that reading it took me longer than usage of well established `while` loop. I am working with other developers and everyones' experience is different - I feel like true art is to write something complex in simple way :)

Answer (score 1):

If `values` is a list with *arbitrary* values, you can return all items *twice* i.e.

```
{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6} -> 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
                                           | <- [6..4] -> |
```

And then use good old *Linq*:

```
List<int> values = new List<int> { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };

int startDay = 6;
int endDay = 4;

...

var result = values
  .Concat(days) // <- Repeats days twice
  .SkipWhile(day => day != startDay)
  .TakeWhile(day => day != endDay)  
  .Append(endDay)
  .ToList();
```

If you want to generate *consequent* numbers mod `week` (`week == 7` in your case), you don't need `values` list at all:

```
int startDay = 6;
int endDay = 4;
const int week = 7;

var result = Enumerable
  .Range(startDay, (endDay - startDay + week + 1) % week)
  .Select(day => day % week)
  .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use this simple method using [`Enumerable.Range`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.range?view=net-7.0) and [`Prepend`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.prepend?view=net-7.0):

```
public static IEnumerable<int> GetRange(int startValue, int endValue, int zero = 0)
{
    if (startValue < endValue)
    {
        return Enumerable.Range(startValue, endValue - startValue + 1);
    }
    
    return Enumerable.Range(zeroValue, endValue - zero + 1).Prepend(startValue);
}
```

---

```
int startValue = 6;
int endValue = 4;
List<int> resultList = GetRange(startValue, endValue).ToList();
```